# Simple C# Code Prints Random Garbage

Tags: c#, garbage, console.writeline

```
using System;
class MainClass {

  public static void Main() {
    string name;
    Console.Write("Hello World: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    if (name != null && name == "Test") {
      Console.WriteLine("Test input.");
    } else {
      Console.WriteLine("Test not input.");
    }
  } 

}
```

Hi, above is my simple C# code. I'm new to C#, although I am not new to programming as a whole. When I try this code (which I know has redundancy in the if statement, that's not the point) it prints garbage.

The code works normally, it just starts off like this:

```
Hello World: [6n[H[J[6n
```

I have no clue why it's adding [6n[H[J[6n. I tried looking it up, but I'm really at a loss. This code was working a few days ago, so maybe it's a compiler issue.

If anyone could help out, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code works just fine when I try it.

Comment: At a glance, they look like formatting characters from the console.

Comment: @Scott I am using repl.it, so maybe it is an issue with the compiler.

Comment: I wouldn't trust online compilers to give you the best representation of what's actually happening.  Try [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) or just an empty Visual Studio project, both work fine with this bit of code.

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it, that does do that in that. Maybe they had a recent change. It works in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Scott I have VS, but I was hoping to learn while away from home. I guess I'll just have to deal with the random garbage until I find a better alternative. It works fine for C and Python, however, so I guess it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those are ansi console control codes.  in ansi, [6n is "query cursor position", [h is "home"  and [j is "erase down" http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm

To me, it looks like you were possibly pressing keys like home/delete/etc, and whatever console app you are running in is displaying them instead of interpreting them.

what kind of console are you running it in?  were you pressing other keys while it is waiting?